# GWT Code Splitting?

Tags: java, optimization, gwt

I am getting one confusion on code splitting. Does GWT creates a javascript file for every GWT.runasync. If not how the splitting is performed i.e. how it groups several content of the code from void success from GWT.runasync into the javascript file??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GWT compiler generates another **permutation** file for each instance of `runAsync()`

Permutations are also created for each language, user agent, etc., so if your app calls `runAsync()` twice, targets six user agents and is localized to 10 languages, you'll have 180 permutations:

```
(initial + 2 split chunks) * 6 user agents * 10 languages
```

Each permutation corresponds to one GWT-generated `cache.html` file.

For example, one of these files may contain the initial download JS for Firefox in French.  Another may be "chunk 2" for Safari in German.